# Binary Tree Recursion PrintInOrder function

Tags: java, binary, binary-tree

Given:

```java
public void printInorder() {
    printInorder(root);
}

private void printInorder(Node<E> n) {
    ...
}
```

```java
private static class Node<E> {
    private E data;
    private Node<E> left;
    private Node<E> right;

    private Node(E data) {
         data = data;
         left = right = null;
    }
```

My task is to finish the private Inorder method for it to work with recursion.
What I did so far is:

```
private void printInorder(Node<E> n) {
if (n != null) {
    printInorder(n.left);
    System.out.println(n.data);
    printInorder(n.right);
```

Which is the right answer, I just dont understand exactly why it is right.

I understand that if you enter printInorder(root) to the public method. It will go the private method and first print the left hand side, then "System.out.println" all the data. Then it will go the rightside, but how does it print the data on the right side?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Add a breakpoint, start the debugger and then step through your code statement by statement

Answer (score 0):

Explained the recursion pattern below. Hopefully helps understanding the right node part.

```
printInorder(1) 
    printInorder(2) //left node of 1
        printInorder(4) //left node of 2
            printInorder(null) // left node of 4. does not print anything. 
        System.out.println(4);
        printInorder(null); // right node of 4 
    System.out.println(2);
    printInorder(5); //referring right node of 2
        printInorder(null); // left node of 5 . No print here
    System.out.println(5);
    printInorder(null); // right node of 5. No print here
System.out.println(1);
    printInorder(3); // right node of 1
        printInorder(6) // left node of 6
            printInorder(null) // left node of 3. does no print here
        System.out.println(6);
        printInorder(null); // right node of 6 . No print here
    System.out.println(3);
        printInorder(7); //referring right node of 3
            printInorder(null); // left node of 7 . No print here
        System.out.println(7);
        printInorder(null); // right node of 7. No print here
```